# Android: How to bring android default launcher on back button press?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I want to bring the android default launcher on back button press, but I'm getting a dialog box style launcher. Also, I cannot call finish() because this is not my first activity and some of the previous activities are also not finished. Here is my code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[image: android_launcher]
[image: launcher_im_getting]

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this line from your code and run again

```
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work. In that case it automatically takes category as CATEGORY_DEFAULT and again a dialog is showing

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent."yourFlagName");

there are lot of flags to work with
try if that could help you